SQL Server created user returns as "guest" with "SELECT USER, USER_NAME()"
On a fresh SQL Server container, with image mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest I login as "sa" and create a database, two schemas and a login/user.
-- USE master
-- <create database, schema data, liquibase>
CREATE LOGIN kpadmin WITH PASSWORD = '<password>'

USE <database>
GO
CREATE USER kpadmin FOR LOGIN kpadmin WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = data;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA ::data TO kpadmin;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA ::liquibase TO kpadmin;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO kpadmin;
GRANT CONNECT TO kpadmin;

Afterwards when I log into the user kpadmin in SSMS and run the query
SELECT USER, USER_NAME(), SYSTEM_USER, SUSER_SNAME(), CURRENT_USER

the output is:
guest   guest   kpadmin kpadmin guest

Why is USER and USER_NAME() guest here? Should it not be kpadmin. How can I fix this, what did I overlook? This inevitably messes up running Liquibase with this user.

Unexpected error running Liquibase: Cannot use default schema name data on Microsoft SQL Server because the login schema of the current user (guest) is different and MSSQL does not support setting the default schema per session.

(Same issue when using different name for user and login)

I bet if you add SELECT DB_NAME(), USER, USER_NAME(), SYSTEM_USER, SUSER_SNAME(), CURRENT_USER you'll get master for the first column, and you (correctly) created the USER in a user database.

Yes, DB_NAME() does return master. And if i run
USE <database> GO SELECT DB_NAME(), USER, USER_NAME(), SYSTEM_USER, SUSER_SNAME(), CURRENT_USER
it returns what i would expect: <database>, kpadmin, kpadmin....
I suppose then the problem lies mostly with liquibase, and that it does not correctly use the correct database(?)

As an example, if I create the LOGIN and USER with the following statements, and then connect and run your statements the results are as expected; guest in master and kpadmin in Sandbox.

I assume you didn't define the database to connect to in Liquibase; that's a different problem to what you describe.

In liquibase.properties im currently using this:
liquibase.liquibaseCatalogName: <database> liquibase.liquibaseSchemaName: liquibase liquibase.command.defaultCatalogName: <database> liquibase.command.defaultSchemaName: data

I'm afraid I know nothing about Liquibase; I came here due to the SQL Server tags, which the question asked about.

fair, ill remove the SQL tag(s). thanks for the help though. It helped me in the right direction :)

Perhaps it helps running: ALTER LOGIN [kpadmin] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = [new_default_database]
